# Is the reduced group $C^*$-algebra quasidiagonal

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be an amenable group. I wonder whether it is true that the reduced group $C^*$-algebra $C_r^*(G)$ is quasidiagonal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true for countable discrete groups by the celebrated Quasidiagonality Theorem of Tikuisis-White-Winter (Quasidiagonality of nuclear C∗-algebras. Ann. of Math. (2) 185 (2017), no. 1, 229–284.)

Comment: If G is a uncoutable discrete group, does the above conclusion also hold?

Comment: Quasidiagonality is a local property for $C^\ast$-algebras (this follows for instance by Voiculescu's characterisation of quasidiagonality combined with Arveson's extension theorem). By writing your uncountable group as a direct limit of countable subgroups, you also obtain quasidiagonality for uncountable discrete groups.

Comment: Thanks, Pro Gabe. Please forgive my stupidity. If the amenable group  is not discrete, does there exist a counterexample to show that the associated reduced group $C^*$-algebra is quasidiagonal?

Comment: There exist non-discrete amenable groups with non-quasidiagonal C*-algebras, see [Beltiţă, Ingrid; Beltiţă, Daniel, Quasidiagonality of C*-algebras of solvable Lie groups. Integral Equations Operator Theory 90 (2018)] for an example.

Comment: Pro Gabe, may I ask you another question? My teacher told me that separable simple nuclear C∗-algebras have  been completely classified . I wonder which problems do most operator algebraists concern about nowadays?

Comment: @mathbeginner your teacher has omitted some key-adjectives (words like Z-stable, for instance)

Comment: @mathbeginner You go to a conference to find out, or you browse sites like https://arxiv.org/